# Pause execution without breakpoint

Tags: java

For instance, I have a `for()` without any contents on my code, and I need debug it to check if it is ok. In javascript I could call `debugger;` inside it to pause execution in this point.

In Java I currently needs to create some code internally then enable breakpoint on it on IDE on this line. Same occur with `if()` or similar statements.

```java
for (Element element: elements) {
    // Need stop here.
}
```

Currently I do:

```java
for (Element element: elements) {
    Element elementB = element; // Breakpoint
}
```

Comment: As already stated, there's no such thing like a special `debugger` keyword, to stop the execution and inspect the application state. But you can use [assertions in your code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) and enable assertions upon the application startup. To enable assertions add `-ea` to VM arguments.

Comment: Some debuggers allow to place a **watch** on the `element`. Whether that works I am uncertain (IDE dependent).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like `debugger` in Java.

What you can do is, if you are using an IDE, you can set a breakpoint and launch your application in `debug` mode. It stops the execution there.

If you are using eclipse, here is an excellent step by step guide http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but i would think you can add a System.out.println() statement inside the for and add a debug point on that.